# How to send only error logs via logstash shipper

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder, logstash-file

I am using Logstash to output JSON message to an API. I am reading logs from a log file. My configurations are working fine and it is also sending all the messages to the API. 
Following is the sample log file:

**Log File:**

```
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:52:59,862]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Successfully created the Axis2 service for Proxy service : TestServiceHttp {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService}
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:59:04,893]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/TestServiceHttp.TestServiceHttpHttpSoap12Endpoint********* Sending Message to the Queue*****WSAction: urn:mediate********* Sending Message to the Queue*****SOAPAction: urn:mediate********* Sending Message to the Queue*****MessageID: urn:uuid:d1bbe24a-2ce3-497f-8224-d260b0632506********* Sending Message to the Queue*****Direction: request********* Sending Message to the Queue*****Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><name> Omer</name></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:59:04,925]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} -  This engine will expire all callbacks after : 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler}
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:59:04,933] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} -  The system cannot infer the transport information from the jms:/Customer.01.Request.Queue.01?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue URL. {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils}
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:59:04,949] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the jms:/Customer.01.Request.Queue.01?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue URL.
        at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:81)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.prepareMessageContext(OperationClient.java:288)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 12:59:05,009]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/TestServiceHttp.TestServiceHttpHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:d1bbe24a-2ce3-497f-8224-d260b0632506, Direction: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Unexpected error during sending message out, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><name> Omer</name></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 13:00:04,890]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://Omer-PC:8280/services/TestServiceHttp.TestServiceHttpHttpSoap12Endpoint] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
ent.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:530)
        at org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:294)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 13:01:40,447]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Shutdown hook triggered.... {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 13:01:40,464]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Gracefully shutting down WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus... {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 13:01:40,477]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Starting to switch to maintenance mode... {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement}
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-07 13:01:40,481]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener} -  JMS Listener Shutdown {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener}
```

Following is my configuration file:

**Configuration File:**

```
input {
 stdin {}

    file {
        path => "C:\WSO2Environment\wso2esb-4.9.0\repository\logs\wso2carbon.log" 
        type => "wso2"
        start_position => "beginning"
         codec => multiline {
            pattern => "(^\s*at .+)|^(?!TID).*$"
            negate => false
            what => "previous"
    }

    }
}

filter {

    if [type] == "wso2" {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "TID:%{SPACE}\[%{INT:SourceSystemId}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:ProcessName}\]%{SPACE}\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:MessageType}%{SPACE}{%{JAVACLASS:MessageTitle}}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Message}" ]
            add_tag => [ "grokked" ]        
        }
        mutate {
          gsub => [
             "TimeStamp", "\s", "T",
             "TimeStamp", ",", "."
           ]
        }


    }
    if !( "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] ) {
        grok{
              match => [ "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:StackTrace}" ]
              add_tag => [ "grokked" ]  
        }
        date {
                match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss:SSS" ]
                target => "TimeStamp"
                timezone => "UTC"
            }
    }

    if ( "multiline" in [tags] ) {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:StackTrace}" ]
            add_tag => [ "multiline" ]
            tag_on_failure => [ "multiline" ]       
        }
        date {
                match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss:SSS" ]
                target => "TimeStamp"

            }
    }

}

output {
    stdout { }
     http {
        url => "http://localhost:8086/messages"
        http_method => "post"
        format => "json"
        mapping => ["TimeStamp","%{TimeStamp}","MessageType","%{MessageType}","MessageTitle","%{MessageTitle}","Message","%{log_EventMessage}","SourceSystemId","%{SourceSystemId}","StackTrace","%{log_StackTrace}"]

    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

The configuration file is working correctly and sending all the log entries to the API, but I only want to send error logs to the API. So, I want to place a check on **"MessageType"** in which I am getting the Log Level that If it's value is **"ERROR"** only then it should send messages through to the API otherwise logstash should discard the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your logstash configuration in the filter section you can use add tag based on your if condition. And in the output add if statement that checks if the tag error is present it will send otherwise it ignores.

After the following if statement:

```
if [type] == "wso2" {
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "TID:%{SPACE}\[%{INT:SourceSystemId}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:ProcessName}\]%{SPACE}\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:MessageType}%{SPACE}{%{JAVACLASS:MessageTitle}}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Message}" ]
        add_tag => [ "grokked" ]        
    }
    mutate {
      gsub => [
         "TimeStamp", "\s", "T",
         "TimeStamp", ",", "."
       ]
    }


}
```

Add the following statement in your filter:

```
    if "grokked" in [tags] {
        grok {
             match => ["MessageType", "ERROR"]
             add_tag => [ "loglevelerror" ]
        }   
    }
```

Then in your output make following changes:

```
output {

    if "loglevelerror" in [tags] {
        stdout { }
         http {
        url => "http://localhost:8086/messages"
        http_method => "post"
        format => "json"
        mapping => ["TimeStamp","%{TimeStamp}","MessageType","%{MessageType}","MessageTitle","%{MessageTitle}","Message","%{log_EventMessage}","SourceSystemId","%{SourceSystemId}","StackTrace","%{log_StackTrace}"]

        }
    }
}
```

I tested it out on my machine using stdout. It works fine. Hope it helps!